# Logstash geoip random failures

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, geoip, logstash-configuration

I'm using logstash to process the logs from dnsmasq.
In the DNS responses I use the 'geoip' filter to enrich the request with the location information. Unfortunately some request are enriched with the geolocation information and others not.

## Geolocation code:

```
      geoip {
        source => "serverip"
      }
```

## List of sample IPs without geolocation

```
104.156.81.217
104.156.85.217
104.16.92.65
104.16.93.65
104.16.94.65
104.16.95.65
104.16.96.65
104.20.5.131
104.20.6.131
104.20.77.18
104.20.78.18
104.244.43.135
104.244.43.167
104.244.43.231
104.244.43.39
104.244.43.7
104.28.30.27
104.28.31.27
104.40.196.5
104.41.231.130
104.45.95.112
104.47.151.128
104.71.97.80
104.84.200.206
104.90.129.122
104.90.176.199
104.90.176.77
104.94.60.210
104.98.119.204
104.98.150.212
162.255.119.124
185.118.208.20
185.19.196.101
185.54.150.54
185.63.147.12
191.232.139.13
191.233.80.151
191.239.8.125
192.229.233.25
23.101.51.170
23.196.235.245
23.196.247.114
23.196.249.86
23.196.255.139
23.197.0.60
23.199.209.223
23.235.33.217
23.235.37.217
23.97.173.24
```

## Successful entry:

```
{
         "message" => "May 27 18:17:16 dnsmasq[385]: reply www.google.com is 216.58.213.228",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-05-27T18:17:17.147Z",
            "path" => "/var/log/dnsmasq.log",
            "host" => "dns",
            "type" => "dnsmasq",
    "reqtimestamp" => "May 27 18:17:16",
         "program" => "dnsmasq",
             "pid" => "385",
          "action" => "reply",
          "domain" => "www.google.com",
        "function" => "is",
        "serverip" => "216.58.213.228",
           "geoip" => {
                      "ip" => "216.58.213.228",
           "country_code2" => "US",
           "country_code3" => "USA",
            "country_name" => "United States",
          "continent_code" => "NA",
             "region_name" => "CA",
               "city_name" => "Mountain View",
             "postal_code" => "94043",
                "latitude" => 37.41919999999999,
               "longitude" => -122.0574,
                "dma_code" => 807,
               "area_code" => 650,
                "timezone" => "America/Los_Angeles",
        "real_region_name" => "California",
                "location" => [
            [0] -122.0574,
            [1] 37.41919999999999
        ]
    }
}
```

## Failed entry:

```
{
         "message" => "May 27 18:15:50 dnsmasq[385]: reply e5884.d.akamaiedge.net is 23.197.8.251",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-05-27T18:15:51.697Z",
            "path" => "/var/log/dnsmasq.log",
            "host" => "dns",
            "type" => "dnsmasq",
    "reqtimestamp" => "May 27 18:15:50",
         "program" => "dnsmasq",
             "pid" => "385",
          "action" => "reply",
          "domain" => "e5884.d.akamaiedge.net",
        "function" => "is",
        "serverip" => "23.197.8.251"
}
```

## Complete Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/dnsmasq.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "dnsmasq"
  }
}

# Mar 15 20:13:05 dnsmasq[346]: query[A] imap.gmail.com from 192.168.0.140
# Mar  2 20:38:45 dnsmasq-dhcp[11856]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.0.152 60:67:20:72:df:00 E0199149
# Mar 15 21:55:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[346]: 3806132383 DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.0.80 04:0c:ce:d1:af:18 Air-de-irobot
# Mar 16 08:54:31 dnsmasq-dhcp[346]: 4280587370 DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.0.158 48:9d:24:ae:0e:00 BB-JP
# Mar 16 08:18:49 dnsmasq[346]: /etc/pihole/gravity.list ssl.google-analytics.com is 192.168.0.2

filter {
  if [type] == "dnsmasq" {
    grok {
      match =>  [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:reqtimestamp} %{USER:program}\[%{NONNEGINT:pid}\]\: ?(%{NONNEGINT:num} )?%{NOTSPACE:action} %{IP:clientip} %{MAC:clientmac} ?(%{HOSTNAME:clientname})?"]
      match =>  [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:reqtimestamp} %{USER:program}\[%{NONNEGINT:pid}\]\: ?(%{NONNEGINT:num} )?%{USER:action}?(\[%{USER:subaction}\])? %{NOTSPACE:domain} %{NOTSPACE:function} %{IP:clientip}"]

      match =>  [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:reqtimestamp} %{USER:program}\[%{NONNEGINT:pid}\]\: %{NOTSPACE:action} %{DATA:data}"]
    }

    if [action] =~ "DHCPACK" {
      if ![clientname] {
        mutate {
          add_field => { "clientname" => "No name" }
        }
      }
      aggregate {
        task_id => "%{clientip}"
        code => "map['clientmac'] = event['clientmac']; map['clientname'] = event['clientname'];"
        map_action => "create_or_update"
        # timeout = 0 sets the timeout to the default value 1800 seconds.
        timeout => 172800
      }
    } else if [action] == "query" {
      aggregate {
        task_id => "%{clientip}"
        code => "event['clientmac'] = map['clientmac']; event['clientname'] = map['clientname']"
        map_action => "update"
      }
      if ![clientname] {
        mutate {
          add_field => { "clientname" => "%{clientip}" }
        }
      }
      if ![clientmac] {
        mutate {
          add_field => { "clientmac" => "%{clientip}" }
        }
      }
    } else if [action] == "reply" {
        mutate {
          rename => { "clientip" => "serverip" }
        }
      geoip {
        source => "serverip"
      }
    } else
    {
      drop{}
    }
  }
}
output {
# elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Logstash version (2.3.2) bundles the [logstash `geoip` filter](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-geoip) 2.0.7, which in turn includes an old Maxmind's GeoIP database from 2013 (`GeoLiteCity-2013-01-18.dat`) as can be seen from the debug log

```
Using geoip database {:path=>"/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/2.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-geoip-2.0.7/vendor/GeoLiteCity-2013-01-18.dat", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/filters/geoip.rb", :line=>"97", :method=>"register"}
```

Maxmind has a new GeoIP2 service that you can try [here](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo) and which will correctly geocode all the IPs from your list above.

As far as Logstash `geoip` is concerned, the switch from GeoIP to GeoIP2 [has been made in March](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-geoip/commit/a0ef0d3877bf84cedfbcac6229a191c1d96694cc) and will be available in the [next Logstash 5.0 version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/alpha2.html#_filter_plugins_2).

Comment: OMG. This answer made it clear to me. In my case I was trying to parse the 10.101.xxx.xxx addresses that were in my log. I was always getting geoip lookup failure... And for a reason. Those are private addresses.

Comment: @Wexoni yep, there's no way that Logstash can geocode private IP addresses.